# Using a variable in Android Layout Call

Tags: java, android

I want to make a simple call to layout resources I already have in Android app as below. All I need to do is to be able to use a variable such as myInteger (having values such as 1,2,3) and call R.layout.("fragment_main"+myInteger) instead of calling R.layout.fragment_main2. To make it clear I need Android to recognize "fragment_main"+myInteger as fragment_main2 allowing me to use a variable

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main2, container, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
    textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> recognize "fragment_main"+myInteger as fragment_main2 allowing me to
>   use a variable

Use `getIdentifier` to get layout id using layout file name as:

```
int layoutID =getResources().getIdentifier("layout"+ myInteger, 
                             "layout", getActivity().getPackageName()); 

 View rootView = inflater.inflate(layoutID, container, false);
```